# NoMethodError in ProductsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" and I've run in to this issue in **Chapter 7, Task B: Validation and Unit Testing**. Any help would be appreciated.

When I try to add a new entry this is the error I get.

---

```
undefined method `titles' for #Product:0x007fa6fcbf28e0
```

Extracted source (around line #30):

> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   if @product.save
>     format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
>     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
>   else
> ```
>
> if @product.save is line 30.

---

This started after adding these lines to my **products.rb** in **/rails/depot_a/app/models**

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :titles, :description, :image_url, presence: true
validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
validates :title, uniqueness: true
validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG, or PNG image.'
}
end
```

---

This is my **products_controller.rb** in **/rails/depot_a/app/controllers** which was mentioned in the error.

```
   class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

ruby 2.0.0p353

Rails 4.0.3

Comment: `validates :titles,...` looks obviously suspect, if this model has a `:title` property. Make it singular `validates :title,...`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - That was it. Can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if you write this as an answer instead of a comment, mikkxx will be able to "accept" it and you will get points.